# Something Weird Happening w/ Blockchain, Gas fee is hold and historical ETH balance is changed

Tags: gas-refund

I am trying to send ETH from Ledger to CoinMetro account. I tried 4 times, with slow, medium and fast options. Each time it failed due to "out of gas" error. The 4th one failed immediately. I did some research and my understanding is that if it fails you get the funds back with the gas fees. So far, I got the bulk of my ETH, but I did not receive the gas fees. One interesting thing I noticed is that, Ledger Live keeps track of how much coin you have over time. On September 11 I had 1.93 ETH, now when I hover my mouse for previous dates, it shows that I had 1.90 ETH on September 11. The difference is the gas fees that I lost during the 4 attempted transactions. I am so confused why this is happening. Can you help me claim my eth? Links to blockexplorer are below. Any help is much appreciated.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0c3c60a41c26be4c05408e1a6d07c9d75226482f9f2f8c117d4ba9d244eb3080

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8a739d43df5bf5c1613103ce9221a61535577d67648bb203d15108d52bca4100

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x768b3046f0c99cc9355b6d5d35c57fe0e7bdfc1b20e42cc85ec332ae9273d2b9

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe413d8bfce0cc2c4e854ab197cb9bf391f6e2c6a03a5eaa480b1c44c7d27e7c6

Comment: Note that when a transaction is failed, it will give you back ETH you supposed to send if it was successful, but it won't give you back the fee you spent!

Comment: Ahmad, thank you. Basically, every time you try to do transaction. You are taking the risk of loosing your gas fee. That stinks. Thank you for reply.